# Arduino : send data via satellite (or other solutions) without GSM

Tags: arduino, low-power, gps, gsm, satellite

I'm a researcher.  I'm looking to build a very tiny embedded system with low power consumption. I must send data from the desert and above the ocean. To do that I think that my single option is to use satellite transmission (and not GSM.)

Thus, I found Iridium Satellite (RockBLOCK) but my main issue is that their Arduino module is too big for my project (4cm of length and too heavy.)

Do you know if there is other module to send data via satellite with Arduino? If not, do you know other microcontroller which can do that? (Using Arduino is not mandatory for me.)

Comment: This is effectively a shopping question which is off-topic here.  But I think you're going to find that the selection of Iridium transceivers is limited.  I also suspect that the RockBLOCK at a mere 76.0 x 51.5 x 19.0mm is likely about as small as such a device can be made.

Comment: @nanofarad A patch antenna measuring about 30x30mm is all that’s needed for Iridium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Iridium 9603 module is the smallest satellite comms device that I know of.  It’s about the same size as a patch antenna (which you’ll unavoidably need).

Comment: That is only a transceiver, not a complete solution, so will require additional circuitry.  The vast majority of microcontrollers could be used, Arduino is physically much larger than you need.